# Which Data Structure is faster for Insert and Deletion

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a recursive function that works on an (NxN) matrix per each call. The main operation on this matrix will be inserting some new columns or deleting some columns at different indices. I mean, inserting or deleting columns is not specific to predefined indices.
For instance, the function receives a 6x6 matrix and may insert two columns, one to the end of the matrix and one after the index 3. Also, it deletes one column at index 2. Then it will call itself again with the new matrix, which will be a 7x7 matrix.

I want to know what is the most efficient data structure for this matrix in c++.
Time efficiency is critical, and this function may repeat numerous times during the program.

EDIT:
This function will do some computations based on the created matrix per each call, so the access rate of matrix elements is high as well.

Comment: Careful! When people implement `std::vector` they have to make many assumptions about the access patterns and expected usage.  Certainly there exist cases where even std::vector is not the most efficient data structure, based on some very specific use case.  But in almost every case, it's fine.  So when you say "most efficient data structure", you must also specify the access pattern, otherwise, it's just opinionated generalization.  For example, You can simply keep a journal of where each insertion was made.  That's blindingly fast for writes, but reading requires reconstructing everything.

Comment: It depends.  A data structure that has preallocated space will be fast at inserting or deleting within that space.  Otherwise, a linked-list based structure only has to modify a few links to insert or remove an element (finding the element may take a while).  You are allowed to mix them too.  For example `std::vector<std::list<>>` may be more efficient than using only a vector or only a list.

Comment: An array of pointers pointing to individual columns seems like the most obvious candidate for this kind of sizes (so, a column-major non-contiguous representation). I wouldn't bother with linked lists.

Comment: Don't optimize one usage of the structure without taking the other usages into account.  You run the risk of utterly crippling one of the other use cases and this may have a significant negative impact. For example, if you insert and delete columns frequently and rarely or never iterate the matrix to look at the data in it, the structure you would use is very different from the structure you would use if you frequently iterate the matrix. If you do more accessing of the data in the matrix, pretty much anything you do to arrange the data for easier inserts and deletes will slow the program.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you, I create new matrix at each step and I call another function to do some computations on it. So, I have inserting, deleting and accessing data with the same percent.